# how to disbale tls certificates and authentication to the kubernetes api server

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to disable tls authentication (https) from my kuberentes api server:
this is the kube-apiserver config :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kube-apiserver
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  containers:
  - name: kube-apiserver
    image: "bcmt-registry:5000/gcr.io/google-containers/kube-apiserver-amd64:v1.9.2"
    command:
    - /usr/local/bin/kube-apiserver
    - --insecure-bind-address=127.0.0.1
    - --apiserver-count=1
    - --etcd-servers=https://172.16.1.7:2379
    - --etcd-cafile=/etc/etcd/ssl/ca.pem
    - --etcd-certfile=/etc/etcd/ssl/etcd-client.pem
    - --etcd-keyfile=/etc/etcd/ssl/etcd-client-key.pem
    - --allow-privileged=true
    - --service-cluster-ip-range=10.254.0.0/16
    - --secure_port=8443
    - --insecure_port=8085
    - --advertise-address=172.16.1.7
    - --admission-control=NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,DefaultStorageClass,ResourceQuota
    - --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver.pem
    - --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-key.pem
    - --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem
    - --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/serviceaccount-key.pem
    - --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kubelet.pem
    - --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kubelet-key.pem
    - --runtime-config=extensions/v1beta1/daemonsets=true
    - --cloud-provider=openstack
    - --cloud-config=/etc/kubernetes/cloud.conf
    - --v=1
    - --authorization-mode=RBAC
    - --runtime-config=rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8443
      hostPort: 8443
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
    - containerPort: 8085
      hostPort: 8085
      protocol: TCP
      name: local
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes
      name: etc-kubernetes
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/etcd/ssl
      name: secret-etcd
      readOnly: true

  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes
    name: etc-kubernetes
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/etcd/ssl
    name: secret-etcd
```

i want to be able to reach the api server with this request curl -v http://172.16.1.7:8443 without using certificates and keys or the --insecure mode; any hints please how to disable all that , 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend you to use insecure mode, but to enable it you have 2 CLI [options](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/accessing-the-api/):

- `--insecure-port` to set a port which will be bound in insecure mode
- `--insecure-bind-address` to set an address where the port will be bound.

Comment: --insecure-port=6443 --insecure-bind-address= 172.16.1.7 and the curl http://172.16.1.7:6443 didn't work how to enable the insecure mode ?

Comment: `curl 172.16.1.7:6443` - from which place you call it? I see, you run `kube-apiserver` in the container, so you can set `--insecure-bind-address=0.0.0.0` and  `--insecure-port=6443 `, then add port 6443 to your `ports` definition in `spec`. Then you should be able to connect to the insecure port by call your master server port 6443.

Comment: actually i want to expose my api server to the rest of the network, i did that but with the secure mode and now i want my api server be accessible without authentication and authorization,

Comment: any hints how to remove all things related to the tls authentication and be able to reach the api server without token or certificates ?

Comment: I already wrote above, you can reach the api server without token and certificate using its insecure port. You just need to expose it to the network. You can use `NodePort` type `Service` or use it the same way as you use secured port. You cannot get access to the secured port (8443 in your configuration) without certs. It is impossible.

Comment: yes, with the way i did i cannot reach the api server with the insecure bind address, how to expose it using the nodeport ?

Comment: Just create a service. Check that article - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport. BTW, in your example you call `curl -v http://172.16.1.7:8443`, but should call `curl -v http://172.16.1.7:8085` for access to the insecure port you set in the configuration - `--insecure_port=8085`

Comment: many thanks, is there a way to disable that and use the insecure mode  ?

Comment: kubectl expose pod kube-apiserver-clustered-control-storage-03 --port=8443,8085 --type=NodePort --name=apiserver -n kube-system  i exposed the apiserver the secure NodePort is accessible but the insecure port i got connection refused any hints where am I going wrong ?